# Dual database for redundancy in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently coding a php website. however one of the requirement is to have it connect to two database concurrently and does the same action on the two database. so if one fail, the another will continue. Is it possible for this to work? server in php with mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look into [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

Comment: +1 Although it actually doesn't answer the question ("is this possible... in PHP). But replication is definitively the one right thing, because it is so much easier and superior. For example, when sending data concurrently to 2 databases, and one returns an error, what do you do... did it work or not?